# Proof of harmonic conjugates being symmetric

Tags: analysis

Prove or disprove the following: 
If $u, v :\mathbb R ^2 \to\mathbb R$ are functions and $v$ is a harmonic
conjugate of $u$, then $u$ is a harmonic conjugate of $v$ (in other words, show whether or
not the relation of being a harmonic conjugate is symmetric).

Also,what does it mean for a function to be 'analytic'?

Answer (score 0):

Let $D\subset\mathbb C$ be an open set. A function $f:D\to\mathbb{C}$ is called analytic if at every point of $D$ it is $\mathbb C-$ differentiable. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function). If a function is analytic then the Cauchy-Reiman equations holds for its imaginary and real parts.